# How to install .exe on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 32-bit

I am a complete noob at Linux so the simplest answer is the best answer!

I need to use [Galfit](http://users.obs.carnegiescience.edu/peng/work/galfit/galfit.html) on my laptop. I made a virtual machine (ubuntu 12.04 on vmware player) so I could test if it works suitably well and to see if I need to make a partition and dual boot ubuntu.

So I download the file and I'm stuck. In windows you just run the setup etc. but what do I do here?

Comment: You might be interested in [this question on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file). (How do I install a tar.gz file?)

Comment: .exe is a Windows executable.  Linux doesn't have specific extensions for denoting executables, but uses permissions instead.  If you downloaded the Debian/Ubuntu package, You should be able to just unzip the package and then double-click the galfit file in Nautilus (or whatever they use for a GUI file manager these days).  from the commandline, you would just type ./galfit and hit enter.

Comment: Just run the binary file. All 4 of those files are archive files, so extra the files, then run the (compiled) binary file.  It will be the only file that actually runs.

Comment: @Fischer - The program in question isn't a Windows program so using WINE acomplishes what?

Comment: Sorry it's an "application/x-executable" (is that an .exe?). I shall try these suggestions...

Comment: when I double click, pypar2 pops up, which doesn't appear to help with anything!

Comment: @Ramhound well he said exe, so i thought it's exe, but since it seems that i am wrong, i deleted my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not say *which* file you downloaded, I will assume you downloaded the `.galfit3-debian32.tar.gz` file. This is what is known as a gzipped tarball, [`gzip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) is a compression program (think `winzip`) and [`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) is an archiver, a way of collecting many files into one [archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file). The two are often used together in the *nix world to create compressed archives.

So, in order to get to the executable that is stored inside the archive, you will need to decompress and extract it. Under Ubuntu, the easiest way to do this would be to double click on the archive. Alternatively open a terminal, and run this command:

```
tar xvvzf /path/to/downloaded/galfit3-debian32.tar
```

This will create a file called `galfit` which is your program. You will now need to make it executable by changing its permissions:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/downloaded/galfit
```

You can now run it by running

```
/path/to/downloaded/galfit
```

You might also want to read the `galfit` [manual](http://users.obs.carnegiescience.edu/peng/work/galfit/README.pdf).

Comment: Yes! Thankyou! It was the middle step I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

the file you have downloaded is a kind of compressed file.right click on the file you have downloaded and click extract here.

alternately you can use

> tar xvvzf /home/aswin/downloads/galfit3-debian32.tar.gz

navigate to the directory containing contents of the extracted file in terminal.
you can use cd utility (change directory )

> cd  /home/aswin/downloads/galfit3-debian32

here "galfit3-debian32" is the extracted file and /home/aswin/downloads/galfit3-debian32 is the path.

you have to set permission to execute an executable.it can be done by

> chmod 777 galfit

now you can execute it by typing

> ./galfit